# Can hx-select-oob update several targets?

Tags: htmx

If I understand [the docs](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-select-oob/) correctly it allows

```
<div>
    <div id="alert"></div>
    <button hx-get="/info" 
        hx-select="#info-details" 
        hx-swap="outerHTML"
        hx-select-oob="#alert">
            Get Info!
    </button>
</div>
```

1. replace the whole `<button>` due to the `hx-swap` directive with the content of `#info-details` - via `hx-select="#info-details"` - from the *response sent*.
2. define a 2nd target `hx-select-oob="#alert"` which takes the content from `#alert` from the *response sent*.

Is there any way `hx-select-oob` can have *multiple targets*?

Like `hx-select-oob="#alert,#second-target"`?

Or **how to manage updating multiple targets at once**?

Comment: Is your goal to return html content and copy the same content to multiple targets? If so, then you simply use clss selector instead of ID. If you have multiple content returned then you need to use htmx-swap-oob

Comment: Yes, `htmx-swap-oob` seems to do what I intended. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to return html content and copy the same content to multiple targets - you simply use class selector instead of ID.

If you have multiple content returned, then you need to use [htmx-swap-oob](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-swap-oob/)